# Not able to get all the data in JSON response from Server

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I am trying to retrive json data from server. I am using HttpURLConnection for connecting to server.

I am getting response code as 200 and i am also getting some data. But after some data i get garbage value.

Here's my code:

```
private List<Member> downloadUrl(String myUrl) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 50537;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("RESPONSE CODE", "The response is: " + response);      

        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Read the stream
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while ( is.read(b) != -1)
            baos.write(b);

        Log.d("baos", "BAOS" + baos);
        String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());


        Log.d("JSONR", "JSONR" + JSONResp);
        Log.d("JSONR", "JSONR LENGTH" + JSONResp.length());
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);  // <---- EXCEPTION 
        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            Members.addMember(arr.getJSONObject(i));
            Log.d("MEMBER", "MEMBER" + arr.getJSONObject(i));
        }


        Log.d("MEMBERS", "members error");
        return Members.getMembers();

    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the 'garbage value' you get at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
 InputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = conn.getInputStream();
      int ch;
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) ch);
      }
      return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
      if (is != null) {
        is.close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: the data i am fetching is very large. this methos is also not able to fetch all the data in one go

Comment: It doesn't depend upon data , what is coming in your response

Comment: i have around 250 json object in a json array and i am getting around 30 in repsonse and due to incomplete json array it is throwing an jsonexception while parsing.

Comment: i have edited my question showing where i am getting exception

Comment: @user007 if your data is huge why dont you use `android.util.JsonReader` ?

Comment: I am not getting all the data from the server. Parsing the data is not an issue

Comment: @user007, no you are getting all the data, study carefully `InputStream#read` documentation